# jfrog cli artifact search by filename pattern

Tags: artifact, jfrog-cli

I want to search for a filename pattern across entire JFrog ARM 
without knowing the explicit repository name in the JFrog cli.

```
jfrog rt s "reponame/*pattern*"
```

is giving the results as expected in a specific repo. 
But I have repo1, repo2, repo3, ... so on.
How do I search using wildcard for reponame, below is not working.

```
jfrog rt s "*/*pattern*"
```

Basically I want the jfrog cli equlivalent of the curl GET request search

```
"https://server/artifactory/api/search/artifact?name=*pattern*"
```

Comment: i am trying to figure it out as well, the best thing i can come up with is put your repositories in a variable ex `repos=repo1 repo2 repo3 ...` and loop through them `for repo in "$repos"; do jfrog rt s $repo/$pattern/; done`

Comment: Infact I ended up doing exactly iterating over all repos in a forloop just as you. It is so bad their hyped CLI does not have such a facility using simple commands.

Comment: I haven't tested it out yet, but I have a feeling using REST API via curl -x POST or whatever is the better option (more user friendly, even the syntax looks cleaner) i may spend some time of this if i get anything worthwhile working I will post it here

Answer (score 0):

The JFrog CLI supports doing queries with AQL, so you can format an AQL that matches your query.

```
jf rt s --spec=<(echo '{"files":[{"aql":{"items.find":{"name":{"$match": "*pattern*""}}}}]}')
```

AQL reference doc:
https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/aql-entities-and-fields

Combining different fields should let you build much more intricate patterns, for example, looking in a repo that fits a specific pattern on a particular path

```
jf rt s --spec=<(echo '{
    "files": [
        {
            "aql": {
                "items.find": {
                    "name": {
                        "$match": "start-of-my-file*"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "$match": "*partofmypath*"
                    },
                    "repo": {
                        "$match": "*-technology-dev"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}')
```

Answer (score -2):

This is not for cli client, but an alternative way to get desired feature. Spent some time looking at API here:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API

I recommend to scroll down that page slowly and read in entirety as a lof of possible commands, syntax is excellent, I executed a few searches and they searched  all local repositories. No need to recursively search 1 by 1. Command syntax:

```
 export url="http://url/to/articatory"
 curl --noproxy '*' -x GET "$url/api/search/artifact?name=log4j*"
```

Read link above for more granular search options/syntax.

How I set it up:

```
 alias artpost='curl -X POST "http://url/artifactory/api/search/aql" -T - -u admin:password'
```

Some example usage:

```
 echo 'items.find({"name": {"$match" : "log4j*"}})' | artpost
 echo 'items.find({"$and" : [{"created" : {"$gt" : "2017-06-12"}},{"name": {"$nmatch" : "*surefire*"}}]})' | artpost
```

Comment: Did you read my question fully ? I wanted to know how to do it using jfrog cli client not curl. I already posted what you suggested in the question itself. jfrog releases a cli client if you are not aware of it.

Comment: Yes I read you question. You asked how to search for something. Did you read my answer? First words out: "This is not for cli client..." I posted it in case anyone else stumbles here and just wants to query using curl. I gave you a functional answer that works, without you specifying any restrictions in your question.